# PayPal DoAuthorization, DoCapture and DoVoid

Tags: php, paypal

I am creating a website for auctions using Paypal. Clients pay a small fee to participate, 
and when the offer falls on someone, the others recover their money.

How do I implement `DoAuthorization`, `DoCapture` and `DoVoid` (NVP) methods in php?  I didn't find any tutorial for this case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll be more likely to get good feedback if you can describe the specific technical issue you're trying to deal with and what code you've used so far to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the code samples [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples)?  There are PHP samples for all 3 of these on this page, for both DoDirectPayment and the Express Checkout API's.  The [SDK's](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index) are also very useful as they have all of the code samples as well for PHP.  Between the samples and the SDK's, these will give you a working example, something to build off of.